# How to add TimeOfDay to local notification in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I want the notification to display on particular time which end-user selects it using time picker. i'm confused with the process of how to do that. please guide me to solve this problem.

Getting variable from model:

```
late var selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
```

User picks the time from front-end:

```
Future<Null> selectTime (BuildContext context) async{
    picked =  (await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: model.selectedTime,

    ))!;

    if (picked != null){
      setState(() {
        model.selectedTime = picked;
        this.preferences?.setString("dateValue", model.selectedTime.format(context));
      });
    }

  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
             child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                                  selectTime(context);
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  '${this.preferences?.getString("dateValue") ?? model.defaultTime.format(context)}',
                                ),
                              ),
```

This class contains notifications sepearately.

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final mymodel = myModel();
Future<void> firstNotifications() async{
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  const AndroidNotificationDetails firstNotificationSpecifics =
  AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel id',
    'channel name',
    'channel description',
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('song1'),
    playSound: true,
    enableVibration: false ,
    visibility: NotificationVisibility.secret,
    autoCancel: true,
    timeoutAfter:7000
  );

  const NotificationDetails firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
  NotificationDetails(android: firstNotificationSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule
    (1, null, null, tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: 5)), firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
}
```

But now this code play notification after 5 seconds which i had given manually. but i want the notification to display at the user picked time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the setNotification function after you picked the time

```
Future<Null> selectTime (BuildContext context) async{
    picked =  (await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: model.selectedTime,

    ))!;

    if (picked != null){
      setState(() {
        model.selectedTime = picked;
setNotification(picked);//Call it here
        this.preferences?.setString("dateValue", model.selectedTime.format(context));
      });
    }

  }
  void setNotification( TimeOfDay selectedTime) {
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    // final mymodel = myModel();
    Future<void> firstNotifications() async {
      var initializationSettingsAndroid =
          AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
      var initializationSettings =
          InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

      const AndroidNotificationDetails firstNotificationSpecifics =
          AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'channel id', 'channel name', 'channel description',
              sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('song1'),
              playSound: true,
              enableVibration: false,
              visibility: NotificationVisibility.secret,
              autoCancel: true,
              timeoutAfter: 7000);

      const NotificationDetails firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
          NotificationDetails(android: firstNotificationSpecifics);

          tz.TZDateTime zonedTime = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,selectedTime.hour,
                          selectedTime.minute).subtract(DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset);

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          1,
          null,
          null,
          tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local) ,
          firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reply. but could you please explain me how do i call this function from another screen. Basically the notification displays after pressing the button so currently i call the function like, firstNotifications(). but now since we are passing the parameter how do i should call it from another screen?

Comment: you can add the function in another class and make it static and call it ex: NotificationManager.setNotification(piked)

Comment: Under this code `GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async{ await NotificationManager.setNotification(piked);} `do i need to call like this?

Comment: unfortunately when i press the button its not working.

Comment: because i'm calling from another screen it saying "LateInitializationError: Field 'picked' has not been initialized."

Comment: call it in selectTime function as commented in answer

Comment: yes, i did that. selectTime function is on another screen where they pick time but the button screen is different where they call the notification